# ios 8 custom keyboard Change language in Setting page

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am writing custom keyboard. When I add my keyboard in setting, I saw like this. It show english.

Is it possible to change "English" as other? Is it in plist ? Or where can I change?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, actually this setting is hidden in `info.plist` of the extension, not the one of the container, under NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes.

For changing that, right click on `info.plist` and select `Open as source code`. and then find `PrimaryLanguage`

This string value, en-US (English for the US) by default, expresses the primary language for your keyboard using the pattern `<language>-<REGION>`. You can find a list of strings corresponding to languages and regions at [This Link](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFLocaleIdentifier.c).

Just change it to your custom language and voila! :)

Comment: How can I achieve, that it displays "Multiple Languages"?

Comment: I am working on Xcode 7, it is not hidden, you can change it from info.plist property list without show it as source code, it is under (NSExtension, then under NSExtensionAttributes)

Answer (score 17):

If you want to support multiple languages in the same keyboard you can type "mul" for "PrimaryLanguage" in your keyboard extensions info.plist.

That will display the text "Multiple Languages".

Comment: Thank you! It works, but is there any place where it is documented?

Comment: @PavelAlexeev You can find `"mul" // verMultilingual` in [CFLocaleIdentifier.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFLocaleIdentifier.c). And this file is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) by Apple

Comment: Setting this key to "mul" changes the text correctly, but also messes up the key bindings when using an external keyboard on iPad :(